# Which of the following is the correct way to assign an 'id' attribute to a new EditText control

Tags: android, xml

Which of the following is the correct way to assign an 'id' attribute to a new EditText control

```
<EditText id="exampleId"

<EditText android-ID="@exampleId"

<EditText android:id="@exampleId"

<EditText android:id="@+id/example
```

Comment: None of them. The last one is close, but you're missing a `"`. Your IDE would've indicated which one's were incorrect, and, in fact, would've auto-completed most of it for you. Was this really worth a question?

Answer (score 0):

The one and only way of assigning id(using xml) to an xml element in android is:

```
<EditText

   android:id="@+id/your_id"       

   android:layout_width="wrap_content"

   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```